# Read and write into a txt file using VB.NET with words in between

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, frameworks

I want to open a txt file and write into it `numbers` from `1 to 100` and put between every number `enter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could try is to write the numbers into a StringBuilder and then use it's ToString() method to get the resulting text:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text


Public Class NumberWriter
   Private ReadOnly OutputPath as String = _
          Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "out.txt")


   Public Sub WriteOut()
       Dim outbuffer as New StringBuilder()

       For i as integer = 1 to 100
          outbuffer.AppendLine(System.Convert.ToString(i))
       Next i

       File.WriteAllText(OutputPath, outbuffer.ToString(), true)
   End Sub

   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim writer as New NumberWriter()
      Try
        writer.WriteOut()
      Catch ex as Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good example over at Home and Learn

```
 Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test2.txt"

If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
    objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text)
    objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the "My.Computer.FileSystem" namespace, like:

```
Dim str As String = ""
For num As Int16 = 1 To 100
  str += num.ToString & vbCrLf
Next
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Working\Output.txt", str, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [System.IO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx), especially the [System.IO.File class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx).